# Error when trying to UNION ALL in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2000, implicit-conversion

Good day mates,

I am having a trouble to execute this query in SQL Server 2000.

```
ALTER   procedure [dbo].[spDirectShareholdng]
as
begin

-- query to get the list shares acquired by directors through Allotment (grouped byClient,director,date) for cash

   SELECT DISTINCT  
      CMS_ORGANIZATION.REG_NAME AS [Client Name], 
      CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID AS [Client ID], 
      CMS_INDIVIDUAL.FULL_NAME,  'SHARES' AS [STOCK SHARES DEBENTURE], 
--      SUM(ISNULL(SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_FOR_CASH_NUM, 0)) AS [No Of Acquired], 
      ISNULL(SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_FOR_CASH_NUM, 0) AS [No Of Acquired], 
      CMS_ORG_SHARES.SHARE_TYPE, 
      SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.PAID_UP_PRICE_PER_SHARE, 'HOLDER' AS [HOW HELD], 
       'Allotment' as [Remarks], 
      SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.ALLOTMENT_DATE AS [Acquired Date], 
      'CASH' AS [Acquired Consideration] ,
      'A' AS AcqOrTransf, CMS_MASTER_SETUP.DESCRIPTION As Prefix, CMS_MASTER_SETUP_1.DESCRIPTION As Sufix,CMS_ORG_SHARES.PAR_VALUE, 
      CMS_INDIVIDUAL.GENDER , SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.ISSUED_PRICE_PER_SHARE as [Consideration]
FROM         CMS_ORGANIZATION INNER JOIN
      CMS_SHAREHOLDER ON CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_SHAREHOLDER.ORG_ACTOR_GUID INNER JOIN
      CMS_INDIVIDUAL ON CMS_SHAREHOLDER.SHAREHOLDER_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_INDIVIDUAL.IND_ACTOR_GUID INNER JOIN
      CMS_SHAREHOLDER_SHAREHOLDING ON 
      CMS_SHAREHOLDER.SHAREHOLDER_PK = CMS_SHAREHOLDER_SHAREHOLDING.SHAREHOLDER_GUID INNER JOIN
      SAS_SHARES_CERT ON CMS_SHAREHOLDER.SHAREHOLDER_ACTOR_GUID = SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_CERT_OWNER_ACTOR_GUID INNER JOIN
      SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT ON SAS_SHARES_CERT.ALLOTMENT_GUID = SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.ALLOTMENT_PK INNER JOIN
      PRM_WIP ON SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.WIP_GUID = PRM_WIP.WIP_PK INNER JOIN
      CMS_ORG_SHARES ON CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_ORG_SHARES.ORG_ACTOR_GUID AND 
      SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.SHARE_GUID = CMS_ORG_SHARES.ORG_SHARES_PK INNER JOIN
      CMS_DIRECTORSHIP ON CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_DIRECTORSHIP.ORG_ACTOR_GUID AND 
      CMS_INDIVIDUAL.IND_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_DIRECTORSHIP.DIRECTOR_ACTOR_GUID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      CMS_MASTER_SETUP CMS_MASTER_SETUP_1 ON 
                      CMS_INDIVIDUAL.SUFFIX_GUID = CMS_MASTER_SETUP_1.MASTER_SETUP_PK LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      CMS_MASTER_SETUP ON CMS_INDIVIDUAL.PREFIX_GUID = CMS_MASTER_SETUP.MASTER_SETUP_PK
WHERE     (PRM_WIP.UPDATE_STATUS = 'c') AND (SAS_SHARES_CERT.CURRENT_STATUS = 'N') And CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID IN (Select ID from CMS_CLIENT_ID_TEMP)
    AND CMS_DIRECTORSHIP.DATE_OF_CESSATION IS NULL
group by CMS_ORGANIZATION.REG_NAME , CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID , CMS_INDIVIDUAL.FULL_NAME, CMS_MASTER_SETUP.DESCRIPTION, CMS_MASTER_SETUP_1.DESCRIPTION,
      CMS_ORG_SHARES.SHARE_TYPE, SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.PAID_UP_PRICE_PER_SHARE, SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.ALLOTMENT_DATE,CMS_ORG_SHARES.PAR_VALUE,
      SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_FOR_CASH_NUM, CMS_INDIVIDUAL.GENDER, SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.ISSUED_PRICE_PER_SHARE 

UNION ALL 

-- query to get the list shares acquired by directors through Allotment (grouped byClient,director,date) for Non cash

SELECT     CMS_ORGANIZATION.REG_NAME AS [Client Name], CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID AS [Client ID], 
      CMS_INDIVIDUAL.FULL_NAME,  'SHARES' AS [STOCK SHARES DEBENTURE], 
--      SUM(ISNULL(SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_FOR_NON_CASH_NUM, 0)) AS [No Of Acquired], 
ISNULL(SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_FOR_NON_CASH_NUM, 0) AS [No Of Acquired], 
      CMS_ORG_SHARES.SHARE_TYPE, 
      SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.PAID_UP_PRICE_PER_SHARE, 'HOLDER' AS [HOW HELD], 
       'Allotment' as [Remarks], 
      SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.ALLOTMENT_DATE AS [Acquired Date], 
      'NON CASH' AS [Acquired Consideration] ,
      'A' AS AcqOrTransf, CMS_MASTER_SETUP.DESCRIPTION, CMS_MASTER_SETUP_1.DESCRIPTION,CMS_ORG_SHARES.PAR_VALUE, CMS_INDIVIDUAL.GENDER, SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.ISSUED_PRICE_PER_SHARE as [Consideration] 
FROM         CMS_ORGANIZATION INNER JOIN
      CMS_SHAREHOLDER ON CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_SHAREHOLDER.ORG_ACTOR_GUID INNER JOIN
      CMS_INDIVIDUAL ON CMS_SHAREHOLDER.SHAREHOLDER_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_INDIVIDUAL.IND_ACTOR_GUID INNER JOIN
      CMS_SHAREHOLDER_SHAREHOLDING ON 
      CMS_SHAREHOLDER.SHAREHOLDER_PK = CMS_SHAREHOLDER_SHAREHOLDING.SHAREHOLDER_GUID INNER JOIN
      SAS_SHARES_CERT ON CMS_SHAREHOLDER.SHAREHOLDER_ACTOR_GUID = SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_CERT_OWNER_ACTOR_GUID INNER JOIN
      SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT ON SAS_SHARES_CERT.ALLOTMENT_GUID = SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.ALLOTMENT_PK INNER JOIN
      PRM_WIP ON SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.WIP_GUID = PRM_WIP.WIP_PK INNER JOIN
      CMS_ORG_SHARES ON CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_ORG_SHARES.ORG_ACTOR_GUID AND 
      SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.SHARE_GUID = CMS_ORG_SHARES.ORG_SHARES_PK INNER JOIN
      CMS_DIRECTORSHIP ON CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_DIRECTORSHIP.ORG_ACTOR_GUID AND 
      CMS_INDIVIDUAL.IND_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_DIRECTORSHIP.DIRECTOR_ACTOR_GUID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      CMS_MASTER_SETUP CMS_MASTER_SETUP_1 ON 
                      CMS_INDIVIDUAL.SUFFIX_GUID = CMS_MASTER_SETUP_1.MASTER_SETUP_PK LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      CMS_MASTER_SETUP ON CMS_INDIVIDUAL.PREFIX_GUID = CMS_MASTER_SETUP.MASTER_SETUP_PK
WHERE     (PRM_WIP.UPDATE_STATUS = 'c') AND (SAS_SHARES_CERT.CURRENT_STATUS = 'N') And CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID IN (Select ID from CMS_CLIENT_ID_TEMP)
AND CMS_DIRECTORSHIP.DATE_OF_CESSATION IS NULL
group by CMS_ORGANIZATION.REG_NAME , CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID , CMS_INDIVIDUAL.FULL_NAME, CMS_MASTER_SETUP.DESCRIPTION, CMS_MASTER_SETUP_1.DESCRIPTION,
      CMS_ORG_SHARES.SHARE_TYPE, SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.PAID_UP_PRICE_PER_SHARE, SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.ALLOTMENT_DATE,CMS_ORG_SHARES.PAR_VALUE,
      SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_FOR_NON_CASH_NUM, CMS_INDIVIDUAL.GENDER, SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.ISSUED_PRICE_PER_SHARE 

UNION ALL 


-- query to get the list shares acquired by directors through transfer (grouped by Client,director,date) cash type
SELECT  CMS_ORGANIZATION.REG_NAME AS [Client Name], CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID AS [Client ID], 
      CMS_INDIVIDUAL.FULL_NAME, 'SHARES' AS [STOCK SHARES DEBENTURE], 
      --sum(ISNULL(SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_FOR_CASH_NUM, 0)) AS [No Of Shares] ,
    ISNULL(SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_FOR_CASH_NUM, 0) AS [No Of Shares] ,
      CMS_ORG_SHARES.SHARE_TYPE, 
      SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.PAID_UP_PRICE_PER_SHARE, 'HOLDER' AS [HOW HELD], 
      'Transfer' as [Remarks],
      SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_HEADER.TRANSFER_DATE AS [Acquired Date] ,
      -- SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.ALLOTMENT_DATE AS [Acquired Date], 
      'CASH' AS [Acquired Consideration] , 
      'A' AS AcqOrTransf, CMS_MASTER_SETUP.DESCRIPTION, CMS_MASTER_SETUP_1.DESCRIPTION,CMS_ORG_SHARES.PAR_VALUE, CMS_INDIVIDUAL.GENDER, SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_DETAILS.CONSIDERATION as [Consideration]   
FROM         CMS_ORGANIZATION INNER JOIN
      CMS_SHAREHOLDER ON CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_SHAREHOLDER.ORG_ACTOR_GUID INNER JOIN
      CMS_INDIVIDUAL ON CMS_SHAREHOLDER.SHAREHOLDER_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_INDIVIDUAL.IND_ACTOR_GUID INNER JOIN
      CMS_MASTER_COUNTRY CMS_MASTER_COUNTRY_1 ON 
      CMS_INDIVIDUAL.NATIONALITY_GUID = CMS_MASTER_COUNTRY_1.COUNTRY_PK INNER JOIN
      SAS_SHARES_CERT ON CMS_SHAREHOLDER.SHAREHOLDER_ACTOR_GUID = SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_CERT_OWNER_ACTOR_GUID INNER JOIN
      CMS_SHAREHOLDER_SHAREHOLDING ON 
      CMS_SHAREHOLDER.SHAREHOLDER_PK = CMS_SHAREHOLDER_SHAREHOLDING.SHAREHOLDER_GUID INNER JOIN
      SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_DETAILS INNER JOIN
      SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_HEADER ON 
      SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_DETAILS.SHARE_CERT_GUID = SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_HEADER.SHARE_CERT_GUID AND 
      SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_DETAILS.WIP_GUID = SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_HEADER.WIP_GUID INNER JOIN
      PRM_WIP ON SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_DETAILS.WIP_GUID = PRM_WIP.WIP_PK ON 
      SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_CERT_PK = SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_DETAILS.TARGET_SHARE_CERT_GUID INNER JOIN
      CMS_ORG_SHARES ON CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_ORG_SHARES.ORG_ACTOR_GUID INNER JOIN
      SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT ON SAS_SHARES_CERT.ALLOTMENT_GUID = SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.ALLOTMENT_PK AND 
      CMS_ORG_SHARES.ORG_SHARES_PK = SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.SHARE_GUID INNER JOIN
      CMS_DIRECTORSHIP ON CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_DIRECTORSHIP.ORG_ACTOR_GUID AND 
      CMS_INDIVIDUAL.IND_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_DIRECTORSHIP.DIRECTOR_ACTOR_GUID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      CMS_MASTER_SETUP CMS_MASTER_SETUP_1 ON 
                      CMS_INDIVIDUAL.SUFFIX_GUID = CMS_MASTER_SETUP_1.MASTER_SETUP_PK LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      CMS_MASTER_SETUP ON CMS_INDIVIDUAL.PREFIX_GUID = CMS_MASTER_SETUP.MASTER_SETUP_PK
WHERE     (PRM_WIP.UPDATE_STATUS = 'c') AND (SAS_SHARES_CERT.CURRENT_STATUS = 'NT') And CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID IN (Select ID from CMS_CLIENT_ID_TEMP)
AND CMS_DIRECTORSHIP.DATE_OF_CESSATION IS NULL
group by CMS_ORGANIZATION.REG_NAME , CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID , CMS_INDIVIDUAL.FULL_NAME, CMS_MASTER_SETUP.DESCRIPTION, CMS_MASTER_SETUP_1.DESCRIPTION,
      CMS_ORG_SHARES.SHARE_TYPE, SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.PAID_UP_PRICE_PER_SHARE, SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_HEADER.TRANSFER_DATE,CMS_ORG_SHARES.PAR_VALUE,
      SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_FOR_CASH_NUM, CMS_INDIVIDUAL.GENDER, SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_DETAILS.CONSIDERATION 
-- SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.ALLOTMENT_DATE

UNION ALL

-- query to get the list shares acquired by directors through transfer (grouped by Client,director,date) NON - Cash type
SELECT  CMS_ORGANIZATION.REG_NAME AS [Client Name], CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID AS [Client ID], 
      CMS_INDIVIDUAL.FULL_NAME, 'SHARES' AS [STOCK SHARES DEBENTURE], 
      --sum(ISNULL(SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_FOR_NON_CASH_NUM, 0)) AS [No Of Shares] ,
    ISNULL(SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_FOR_NON_CASH_NUM, 0) AS [No Of Shares] ,
      CMS_ORG_SHARES.SHARE_TYPE, 
      SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.PAID_UP_PRICE_PER_SHARE, 'HOLDER' AS [HOW HELD], 
      'Transfer' as [Remarks], 
       SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_HEADER.TRANSFER_DATE AS [Acquired Date] ,
      -- SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.ALLOTMENT_DATE AS [Acquired Date], 
      'NON CASH' AS [Acquired Consideration] , 
      'A' AS AcqOrTransf, CMS_MASTER_SETUP.DESCRIPTION, CMS_MASTER_SETUP_1.DESCRIPTION,CMS_ORG_SHARES.PAR_VALUE, CMS_INDIVIDUAL.GENDER , SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_DETAILS.CONSIDERATION as [Consideration]
FROM         CMS_ORGANIZATION INNER JOIN
      CMS_SHAREHOLDER ON CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_SHAREHOLDER.ORG_ACTOR_GUID INNER JOIN
      CMS_INDIVIDUAL ON CMS_SHAREHOLDER.SHAREHOLDER_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_INDIVIDUAL.IND_ACTOR_GUID INNER JOIN
      CMS_MASTER_COUNTRY CMS_MASTER_COUNTRY_1 ON 
      CMS_INDIVIDUAL.NATIONALITY_GUID = CMS_MASTER_COUNTRY_1.COUNTRY_PK INNER JOIN
      SAS_SHARES_CERT ON CMS_SHAREHOLDER.SHAREHOLDER_ACTOR_GUID = SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_CERT_OWNER_ACTOR_GUID INNER JOIN
      CMS_SHAREHOLDER_SHAREHOLDING ON 
      CMS_SHAREHOLDER.SHAREHOLDER_PK = CMS_SHAREHOLDER_SHAREHOLDING.SHAREHOLDER_GUID INNER JOIN
      SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_DETAILS INNER JOIN
      SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_HEADER ON 
      SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_DETAILS.SHARE_CERT_GUID = SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_HEADER.SHARE_CERT_GUID AND 
      SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_DETAILS.WIP_GUID = SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_HEADER.WIP_GUID INNER JOIN
      PRM_WIP ON SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_DETAILS.WIP_GUID = PRM_WIP.WIP_PK ON 
      SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_CERT_PK = SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_DETAILS.TARGET_SHARE_CERT_GUID INNER JOIN
      CMS_ORG_SHARES ON CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_ORG_SHARES.ORG_ACTOR_GUID INNER JOIN
      SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT ON SAS_SHARES_CERT.ALLOTMENT_GUID = SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.ALLOTMENT_PK AND 
      CMS_ORG_SHARES.ORG_SHARES_PK = SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.SHARE_GUID INNER JOIN
      CMS_DIRECTORSHIP ON CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_DIRECTORSHIP.ORG_ACTOR_GUID AND 
      CMS_INDIVIDUAL.IND_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_DIRECTORSHIP.DIRECTOR_ACTOR_GUID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      CMS_MASTER_SETUP CMS_MASTER_SETUP_1 ON 
                      CMS_INDIVIDUAL.SUFFIX_GUID = CMS_MASTER_SETUP_1.MASTER_SETUP_PK LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      CMS_MASTER_SETUP ON CMS_INDIVIDUAL.PREFIX_GUID = CMS_MASTER_SETUP.MASTER_SETUP_PK
WHERE     (PRM_WIP.UPDATE_STATUS = 'c') AND (SAS_SHARES_CERT.CURRENT_STATUS = 'NT') And CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID IN (Select ID from CMS_CLIENT_ID_TEMP)
AND CMS_DIRECTORSHIP.DATE_OF_CESSATION IS NULL
group by CMS_ORGANIZATION.REG_NAME , CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID , CMS_INDIVIDUAL.FULL_NAME, CMS_MASTER_SETUP.DESCRIPTION, CMS_MASTER_SETUP_1.DESCRIPTION,
      CMS_ORG_SHARES.SHARE_TYPE, SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.PAID_UP_PRICE_PER_SHARE, SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_HEADER.TRANSFER_DATE,CMS_ORG_SHARES.PAR_VALUE,
      SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_FOR_NON_CASH_NUM, CMS_INDIVIDUAL.GENDER, SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_DETAILS.CONSIDERATION 
-- SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.ALLOTMENT_DATE 



-- queries for all acquisitions end here 

UNION ALL 


-- query to get the list shares tranasferred by directors (grouped byClient,director,date) by cash 

SELECT     CMS_ORGANIZATION.REG_NAME AS [Client Name], CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID AS [Client ID], 
      CMS_INDIVIDUAL.FULL_NAME, 'SHARES' AS [STOCK SHARES DEBENTURE], 
      --SUM(ISNULL(SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_FOR_CASH_NUM, 0))  AS [No Of Shares] ,
    ISNULL(SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_FOR_CASH_NUM, 0)  AS [No Of Shares] ,
      CMS_ORG_SHARES.SHARE_TYPE, 
      SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.PAID_UP_PRICE_PER_SHARE, 'HOLDER' AS [HOW HELD], 
      'Transfer' as [Remarks],
      SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_HEADER.TRANSFER_DATE AS [Out Date],
       -- SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.ALLOTMENT_DATE AS [Out Date],
       'CASH' AS [Out Consideration] ,
      'T' AS AcqOrTransf, CMS_MASTER_SETUP.DESCRIPTION, CMS_MASTER_SETUP_1.DESCRIPTION,CMS_ORG_SHARES.PAR_VALUE, CMS_INDIVIDUAL.GENDER , SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_DETAILS.CONSIDERATION as [Consideration]
FROM         CMS_ORGANIZATION INNER JOIN
      CMS_SHAREHOLDER ON CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_SHAREHOLDER.ORG_ACTOR_GUID INNER JOIN
      CMS_INDIVIDUAL ON CMS_SHAREHOLDER.SHAREHOLDER_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_INDIVIDUAL.IND_ACTOR_GUID INNER JOIN
      CMS_ADDRESS ON CMS_INDIVIDUAL.IND_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_ADDRESS.ACTOR_GUID INNER JOIN
      CMS_SHAREHOLDER_SHAREHOLDING ON 
      CMS_SHAREHOLDER.SHAREHOLDER_PK = CMS_SHAREHOLDER_SHAREHOLDING.SHAREHOLDER_GUID INNER JOIN
      SAS_SHARES_CERT ON CMS_SHAREHOLDER.SHAREHOLDER_ACTOR_GUID = SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_CERT_OWNER_ACTOR_GUID INNER JOIN
      SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_DETAILS INNER JOIN
      SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_HEADER ON 
      SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_DETAILS.SHARE_CERT_GUID = SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_HEADER.SHARE_CERT_GUID AND 
      SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_DETAILS.WIP_GUID = SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_HEADER.WIP_GUID ON 
      SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_CERT_PK = SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_HEADER.SHARE_CERT_GUID INNER JOIN
      CMS_ORG_SHARES INNER JOIN
      SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT ON CMS_ORG_SHARES.ORG_SHARES_PK = SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.SHARE_GUID ON 
      CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_ORG_SHARES.ORG_ACTOR_GUID AND 
      SAS_SHARES_CERT.ALLOTMENT_GUID = SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.ALLOTMENT_PK INNER JOIN
      CMS_DIRECTORSHIP ON CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_DIRECTORSHIP.ORG_ACTOR_GUID AND 
      CMS_INDIVIDUAL.IND_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_DIRECTORSHIP.DIRECTOR_ACTOR_GUID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      CMS_MASTER_SETUP CMS_MASTER_SETUP_1 ON 
                      CMS_INDIVIDUAL.SUFFIX_GUID = CMS_MASTER_SETUP_1.MASTER_SETUP_PK LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      CMS_MASTER_SETUP ON CMS_INDIVIDUAL.PREFIX_GUID = CMS_MASTER_SETUP.MASTER_SETUP_PK
WHERE     (SAS_SHARES_CERT.OUT_STATUS = 'T') And CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID IN (Select ID from CMS_CLIENT_ID_TEMP) AND CMS_DIRECTORSHIP.DATE_OF_CESSATION IS NULL
group by CMS_ORGANIZATION.REG_NAME , CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID , 
      CMS_INDIVIDUAL.FULL_NAME,CMS_MASTER_SETUP.DESCRIPTION, CMS_MASTER_SETUP_1.DESCRIPTION,CMS_ORG_SHARES.SHARE_TYPE, 
      SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.PAID_UP_PRICE_PER_SHARE, 
      SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_HEADER.TRANSFER_DATE,CMS_ORG_SHARES.PAR_VALUE,
      SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_FOR_CASH_NUM, CMS_INDIVIDUAL.GENDER, SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_DETAILS.CONSIDERATION 
      -- SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.ALLOTMENT_DATE 

UNION ALL

-- query to get the list shares tranasferred by directors (grouped byClient,director,date) by NON cash 
SELECT     CMS_ORGANIZATION.REG_NAME AS [Client Name], CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID AS [Client ID], 
      CMS_INDIVIDUAL.FULL_NAME, 'SHARES' AS [STOCK SHARES DEBENTURE], 
      --SUM(ISNULL(SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_FOR_NON_CASH_NUM, 0))  AS [No Of Shares] ,
    ISNULL(SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_FOR_NON_CASH_NUM, 0)  AS [No Of Shares] ,
      CMS_ORG_SHARES.SHARE_TYPE, 
      SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.PAID_UP_PRICE_PER_SHARE, 'HOLDER' AS [HOW HELD], 
      'Transfer' as [Remarks],
      SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_HEADER.TRANSFER_DATE,
      -- SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.ALLOTMENT_DATE , 
       'NON CASH' ,
      'T' AS AcqOrTransf , CMS_MASTER_SETUP.DESCRIPTION, CMS_MASTER_SETUP_1.DESCRIPTION,CMS_ORG_SHARES.PAR_VALUE, CMS_INDIVIDUAL.GENDER , SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_DETAILS.CONSIDERATION as [Consideration] 
FROM         CMS_ORGANIZATION INNER JOIN
      CMS_SHAREHOLDER ON CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_SHAREHOLDER.ORG_ACTOR_GUID INNER JOIN
      CMS_INDIVIDUAL ON CMS_SHAREHOLDER.SHAREHOLDER_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_INDIVIDUAL.IND_ACTOR_GUID INNER JOIN
      CMS_ADDRESS ON CMS_INDIVIDUAL.IND_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_ADDRESS.ACTOR_GUID INNER JOIN
      CMS_SHAREHOLDER_SHAREHOLDING ON 
      CMS_SHAREHOLDER.SHAREHOLDER_PK = CMS_SHAREHOLDER_SHAREHOLDING.SHAREHOLDER_GUID INNER JOIN
      SAS_SHARES_CERT ON CMS_SHAREHOLDER.SHAREHOLDER_ACTOR_GUID = SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_CERT_OWNER_ACTOR_GUID INNER JOIN
      SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_DETAILS INNER JOIN
      SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_HEADER ON 
      SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_DETAILS.SHARE_CERT_GUID = SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_HEADER.SHARE_CERT_GUID AND 
      SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_DETAILS.WIP_GUID = SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_HEADER.WIP_GUID ON 
      SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_CERT_PK = SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_HEADER.SHARE_CERT_GUID INNER JOIN
      CMS_ORG_SHARES INNER JOIN
      SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT ON CMS_ORG_SHARES.ORG_SHARES_PK = SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.SHARE_GUID ON 
      CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_ORG_SHARES.ORG_ACTOR_GUID AND 
      SAS_SHARES_CERT.ALLOTMENT_GUID = SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.ALLOTMENT_PK INNER JOIN
      CMS_DIRECTORSHIP ON CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_DIRECTORSHIP.ORG_ACTOR_GUID AND 
      CMS_INDIVIDUAL.IND_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_DIRECTORSHIP.DIRECTOR_ACTOR_GUID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      CMS_MASTER_SETUP CMS_MASTER_SETUP_1 ON 
                      CMS_INDIVIDUAL.SUFFIX_GUID = CMS_MASTER_SETUP_1.MASTER_SETUP_PK LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      CMS_MASTER_SETUP ON CMS_INDIVIDUAL.PREFIX_GUID = CMS_MASTER_SETUP.MASTER_SETUP_PK
WHERE     (SAS_SHARES_CERT.OUT_STATUS = 'T') And CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID IN (Select ID from CMS_CLIENT_ID_TEMP) AND CMS_DIRECTORSHIP.DATE_OF_CESSATION IS NULL
group by CMS_ORGANIZATION.REG_NAME , CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID , 
      CMS_INDIVIDUAL.FULL_NAME,CMS_MASTER_SETUP.DESCRIPTION, CMS_MASTER_SETUP_1.DESCRIPTION,CMS_ORG_SHARES.SHARE_TYPE, 
      SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.PAID_UP_PRICE_PER_SHARE, SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_HEADER.TRANSFER_DATE,CMS_ORG_SHARES.PAR_VALUE,
      SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_FOR_NON_CASH_NUM,
      SAS_SHARES_CERT.SHARE_FOR_NON_CASH_NUM , CMS_INDIVIDUAL.GENDER, SAS_SHARES_CERT_TRANSFER_DETAILS.CONSIDERATION 
      -- SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.ALLOTMENT_DATE 


order by CMS_ORGANIZATION.REG_NAME , CMS_INDIVIDUAL.FULL_NAME, 
    SAS_SHARES_ALLOTMENT.ALLOTMENT_DATE 


end
```

There are 6 parts in this query that union together. If the first 2 parts are executed without the rest, it will works fine. Also if the last 4 parts are executed without the first 2 parts, the command will complete successfully. But if all parts are together executed, it shows this error:

> Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Procedure spDirectShareholding, Line 13
>   Implicit conversion from data type varchar to money is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
>
> Msg 257, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spDirectShareholding, Line 13
>   Implicit conversion from data type varchar to money is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
>
> Msg 257, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spDirectShareholding, Line 13
>   Implicit conversion from data type varchar to money is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
>
> Msg 257, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spDirectShareholding, Line 13
>   Implicit conversion from data type varchar to money is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

I have tried this query in SQL Server 2008 and it works without any error. But my problem here is this query is not possible to be executed successfully in SQL Server 2000. Since my database in SQL Server 2000 cannot be restored in SQL Server 2008 because its not compatible. I have no idea on how to fix this problem.

I did try to use `CONVERT/CAST` function to run the query and it is successful but another error happen in my software.

Sorry for inconvenience caused if you find it is hard to read the long SQL query.

Your comments and advice is really helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was the another error after using CONVERT?

Comment: Error: Unable to complete the request.

Comment: The error was generated from my software maybe the report might not get the right data type of the input. So I could not use CONVERT. The problem is I dont know why it works in SQL Server 2008 but not in SQL Server 2000. Thanks for your comment